# How to run a Java Integration Stage with a different version of JRE?

Tags: java, java-8, datastage, ibm-infosphere

My current InfoSphere Datastage 11.5 has JDK 1.7 installed. In this I have a considerable amount of developments (over a thousand) but I'm developing a specific requirement with a Java Integration Stage that needs a larger version (JDK 1.8 or greater). How can I run this independent Stage with that new version? I don't want to impact what has been developed so far, although of all the developments this is the first with a Java Integration Stage.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

JDK/JRE versions inside the DataStage are updated only with the DataStage itself.
JDK 8 is bundled with DataStage 11.7, so you probably need to upgrade.

There is no "supported" way to run a Java Integration Stage on an additional JDK installed somewhere, and trying to do so will probably break your jobs.